# Triggering a function inside of a controller using states "onEnter" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So my nav is using angular states. And whenever you click an item in the menu it triggers a function that changes the picture in the head, so that there is a different picture on each pages header. This works fine when someone starts on the home page of the site and navigates only through clicking, but when you input the url the function is not triggered. I am trying to use onEnter() to trigger it so I can drop the click and it will work in both situations, but it looks like I am having scope issues and could really use some guidance.

```
app.directive("mainNav", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "js/main-nav.html",
        controller: function() {
        this.tab = tabbytab;

        this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
            return this.tab === checkTab;
        };

        this.setTab = function(activeTab) {
            tabbytab = activeTab;
            window.fbAsyncInit();
        };
        this.imageArray = navImages;
        //minus 1 because tabbytab starts at 1 and the array doesnt of course
        this.currentImage = navImages[(tabbytab - 1)].image;
        console.log(tabbytab);
        this.setImage = function(activeTab) {
            this.currentImage = this.imageArray[tabbytab].image;
        };
    },
    controllerAs: "tab"
};
});
```

And here is my state

```
.state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "js/home.html",
        onEnter: function() {
          tab.setTab(1);
          console.log("on enter function triggered");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain a little more what you mean by scoping issues? What exactly is happening, or not?

Another way that might be a little less complicated would be to use $routeParams https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/. Basically, you can pull in parameters from the route(url) and display the image depending upon the URL.

Comment: Yeah of course, thanks for looking. I was hoping I could trigger my set tab function using on enter, but it says tab is not define in my $stateProvider so I guess that was the wrong route. Looks like the route way is a much better way for me to change page content depending on which route I am in currently. Thanks!